# How do we motivate users to vote and advertise the voting policy?

Tags: discussion, voting

Sparked by another question on meta, I again wanted to reflect on my voting behaviour and the generally accepted practice on 3D Printing SE (3DP:SE) in the current beta stage.

I know this post [Vote early, Vote often](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30/vote-early-vote-often), and I do take it to be still the general guideline on how to vote on 3DP:SE.

I personally do like to vote what I'd call slightly more liberal than conservative and I do have the feeling that this is not the way it is usually handled by other users (as can probably be seen by the fact that only two people on 3DP:SE acquired the civic duty badge).

Also, if I look at the questions from the beginning time of the beta, there were much more votes in general. (This of course might be related to many things as 'more substantial questions and answers', more regular users and time that has passed since the question exists, allowing for more views and hence votes).

If a new question already has 40 views, however, I would expect more than 2 votes on the question. It means that 38 views happened in short time, this is, mainly views by 3DP:SE regulars, not search engine referrals (I strongly asumme this point, I do not have any hard evidence), which did look at the topic but have not been touched by the topic enough to vote up, down, or comment.

In general this probably is pretty regular behavior (seeing my behavior in the reprap forum for example, where I generally only pass to read, not to interact that much). In the phase this SE is in I'd take it as highly beneficial if we could encourage more action in the users (in this thread the most simple one - voting), because missing interaction maybe won't bring users back regularly enough.

Are there any ideas how to get the '[Vote early, Vote often](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30/vote-early-vote-often)' policy across to new users?
(And if applies: do I take a wrong approach - are there enough votes?)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a bit confused with the wording of the last few paragraphs, can you please elaborate or edit the question? Kudos on being one of the Civic Duty badge holders btw!

Comment: I have noticed this tendency as well, and I think not up-voting enough is a bad habit that doesn't benefit anyone. One might think that one cannot upvote a question or answer that isn't perfect, and sometimes you might not have any personal experience on the subject to actually have a strong opinion about it. However, I still think giving new and established users a thumbs up for their effort is crucial for the growth of this site. And eventually, as the site gets larger, the voting system will truly begin to work, as bias from individuals will be averaged out.

Comment: I enhanced the last paragraphs and hope it is more clear now. @Thormod: I agree, when the site gets larger, the voting system will take off on its own, and the reward for user's efforts and good answers will come more easily. What do we do until then?

Answer (score 3):

I think one way to encourage a little more up-voting would be to comment on some of the questions that are 'interesting subject, but not well written', pointing out that a better question will often get better answers, partly through receiving up-votes from other users, and more visibility.