# Remember to vote!

Tags: discussion, voting

In past few months, there are a devastatingly few number of users that cast up votes, and many of users aren't coming back to site, and existing users don't have so much reputation, because no one is voting up great questions / answers.

So... let me start like this..

[THIS IS REALLY DEVASTATING](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all)

We all need to vote up users and try to answer their questions, so we can get more users answering / asking questions. Main reason I'm writing this post is because this is great site, but we need new regular users that are going to vote and ask questions. I think it all came down to 20-30 active users, and rest of users aren't so active.

I'm relatively new to site. I've decided to use it because it helped me a lot, and I'm doing my best to answer the questions. My main concern is also that my answers also don't get any vote up.

So... I'll let it all out. I think that main concern that we need to focus on is motivation.

WE NEED TO MOTIVATE OTHERS TO VOTE. And we all can do that if we vote other users up.

That's from my perspective. Even one vote up motivates you to go further.

I think that I explained what I mean. :) It's all in VOTE UP!

Comment: I'll also point out that we have a very ridiculous amount of questions that no one has selected an answer for. A lot are one time users, others are not. Least this week we do.. which as its the holidays..  I feel like people have been good with +1ing answers lately.

Comment: We're more than a year later, and not come any further. It is a pity to see that e.g. the large forums like Thingiverse get a lot of people and questions while that site lacks the search and voting capabilities of the SE concept. It is really disappointing to see that good answers never get accepted nor that good answers get upvoted.

Comment: [This question is related.](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30/11242). [This answer is also related!](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/285/11242) ... Yes, I cannot relate efficiently enough how important voting is to a Beta site (or any site, for that matter.)

Comment: It's pretty crazy that only four people have cast over 1k votes on this site, and only a dozen have cast over 500. What's going on?

Comment: 18 months later, and only five people have cast over 1k votes on this site, and only 14 have cast over 500.

Comment: Why is this constantly featured

Comment: Can't agree more. But 'WE NEED TO MOTIVATE OTHERS TO VOTE' triggered me. Without introducing the wrong incentive. How about (temporarily) giving +1 rep to the voter for every vote? Considering there are still daily voting limits per user. I would suggest enabling this only above a certain base reputation to avoid new users quickly wanting to increase their reputation by randomly voting. Also, introduce an additional limit of X reps that can be gained in total or per day from voting. And in the UI, show a reminder to vote on questions and answers more actively.

Comment: @Starship-OnStrike - Because no one ever votes?

Comment: @BobOrtiz - Those are the types of changes that aren't available to be opted-in to on a site-per-site basis, and would require an overall of the SE main code base. Suggestions like that should probably be posted on SE.Meta, as they would affect all sites. A 200 rep limit already exists per question, I believe. The +1 per vote seems like a bad idea to me, especially if not applied to all sites, as that would led to imbalanced reputations. Also, the [Electorate badge](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/206/4762) fills in for your missing +1 per vote.

Comment: The existing voting rules work well elsewhere, so they *should* work just as well here. As Davo points out above ([here](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196/remember-to-vote?cb=1#comment703_196) and [here](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196/remember-to-vote?cb=1#comment815_196)), the main issue is footfall and that only 4 (& then later 5) people seem to vote (see the number of users with 1k votes cast).

Comment: I see. This has been an issue for long. I think new methods should be introduced to access new visitors from different channels. Perhaps backlinks from sites like Thingiverse, Printables, YouTube, GitHub, and other channels that have 3D printing users. Referral-like backlinks to earn badges?

Answer (score 18):

I completely agree! I just posted [my own reminder](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/3d-printing-se-beta-status), focusing more on efforts to get us out of Beta.

I'm sorry you can feel discouraged sometimes, I think a lot of users around the Stack Exchange network can feel that way at times.

I think people sometimes forget that an up-vote to an answer isn't necessarily that it was helpful to you, specifically. But, rather that **the answer is a good *quality* answer** and **will be *useful* to others** as well!

Comment: While it is important to votes and vote often, it is worth remembering that we shouldn't just vote willy-nilly. I have noticed that some beta sites, especially in the early days, tend to get rather frenzied voting, which one does not necessarily see in the more established sites, where the voting has settled down and only the (oft mentioned) _awesome_ answers are voted for.

Comment: Voting seems to have been lacking on this site specifically though. We receive a lot of new Stack Exchange users that don't continually come back. So it's hard to teach people the etiquette of voting

Comment: I fully agree with voting on quality rather than just content. I believe the best answers will get more votes anyway, so just bumping all decent answers up one level just keep the site rolling and motivates users. Of course, if the answer isn't good or simply incorrect, there will be no upvote either (but perhaps a comment). :)

Comment: I fully agree with both question and answer. Voting is very important on SE sites and helps with growing a steady userbase.

Answer (score 10):

So, I'm the first who got [**Electorate**](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate) badge. Go guys and fetch that badge. You can only get that badge by voting. This is a very young SE site, and there's need for users that vote, because voting is encouraging others to post and to discuss.

Cheers once again and remember to vote up!

Comment: Wow, it's 2021, and only **SIX** of us have the Electorate badge?

Comment: Sadly, I expect that the same people who don't vote much also don't visit meta much.

Comment: Still six of us; nobody has earned the Electorate badge since 2018. That's very sad.

Answer (score 9):

Strangely enough, I was thinking (prior to reading this post) that this particular SE site was quite good w.r.t. the voting, when compared to some other sites. Most of my questions/answers have received votes, whereas on other (nameless) sites, I have posted a number of questions/answers and not received [m]any votes at all. However, this must be my (inaccurate) perception, as the stats shows that the voting is not at the desired levels.

While it is important to votes and vote often, it is worth remembering that we shouldn't just vote willy-nilly. I have noticed that some beta sites, especially in the early days, tend to get rather frenzied (or, if you will, overly enthusiastic) voting, which one does not necessarily see in the more established sites, where the voting has settled down and only the (oft mentioned) *awesome* answers are voted for. This overly enthusiastic voting can *sometimes* end up giving random votes to questions that are not particularly researched, or answers that are not fully accurate, which maybe do not deserve any votes at all.

I am not sure why this (comparatively) frenzied voting occurs, or why it dies down, nor am I sure what (which?) level of voting is appropriate - although it is obvious that poorly researched questions and inaccurate answers should not be voted up.

Regardless, I would agree that voting *does* act as an incentive to contribute to the site, as well as the idea that voting for a good question, or accurate answer, even if that question/answer does not apply directly to you, because it will help other users. Indeed the latter is the entire premise of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Btw, @Greenonline, nice work with all the edits! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Hmm yeah we might have a minor problem. I know most of my rep is disportionately from question acceptance and unusually low for +1s. I wonder if it has to do with any active member being able to be on the top 50 list their first month, thus people maybe hoarding their upvotes trying to be number one?

Comment: There is a certain amount of [reputation bias as a result of being on a SE site earlier](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288076/is-reputation-really-about-how-hard-you-try-to-help-or-sit-back-and-relax-for-fe). However, there are many blogs/podcasts on how to achieve higher reputation. Most of it stems from answering early and how you format your questions/answers. A little styling goes a long way.

Comment: True, I know that how I was answering questions last year was pittiful compared to my current answers. I hope to have more such improvements this year ;-) That said interesting enough on Android stack overflow and others most of my rep is for +1s on answers 3 or 4 answers after the first. Here however yes most of the time if I answer first I get the acceptance.

Comment: You can check the voting stats [here](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all). That said, I can't really see why people would be hoarding votes. However, as tbm0115 points out in [their comment](http://meta.3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/196/remember-to-vote/199#comment252_201) some anomalies do occur.

Comment: Going to have to get on @darth pixel s case

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the Question. It's [devastating indeed](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=year), the lack of quality control by the crowd.

There are many starting points to do this, but I wrote a Data Explorer query for this site that can serve as a starting point for finding questions to upvote that are *likely* well-formatted or high-quality. Please do a manual review; it's only a starting point.

*Unfortunately I didn't manage to exclude posts that the used UserId already voted on.*

Exclude your own UserId, and choose a minimum and maximum length of the body, for example, 300-1200. Change the Query as desired.

It can be found here: https://data.stackexchange.com/3dprinting/revision/1806674/2194104/find-upvoting-material-likely-high-quality-questions

*Don't forget that especially low reputation users can potentially be motivated easily when they ask a good question, and become active members that grows this community. And older inactive users can be motivated to return as active members when their reputation is growing again.*